Zustand store being undefined upon redirecting to different route
I have an react/next.js application which is using zustand. For context, im trying to create HOC client route guard in next.js.
This is the usage of my zustand store module:
"use client";

import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import {useAuthStore} from "@/store/authStore";
import {useRouter} from "next/navigation";

const ProtectedRoute = <P extends object>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>) => {
    const ComponentWithAuth = (props: P) => {
        const authStore = useAuthStore();
        const router = useRouter();

        console.log(authStore);

        useEffect(() => {
            console.log(authStore);
            if (!authStore.user) router.push("/");
        }, []);

        return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
    };

    return ComponentWithAuth;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;

And this is the component in which the HOC is used ("/app" page):
"use client"

import isAuth from "@/components/layout/protectedRoute";

const Page = () => {
    return <div>App Page</div>
}

export default isAuth(Page);

Now the problem, when i try to access /app through url, directly typing the /app into url bar and hitting enter to navigate authStore is an object of zustand store with all properties etc. When im redirecting to /app page with function bellow which is called on login form submit, the authStore is being undefined on the console.log and later and is crashing application.
const submitForm = async (data: LoginFormValues) => {
    try {
        await login(data);
        const user = await getMe();
        authStore.setUserData(user);
        router.push("/app");
    } catch (e) {}
}

Im just trying to learn react and next js. This approach is what i have found on internet as a solution to client route guard.
I have tried different approaches and before i was calling also refresh with /me requests to figure out if user was logged before. I thought that the async function in the effect was causing that but i was mistaken.

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Hey, first I'ld recommend you to wrap components by passing them as children. Second, I'ld guess isAuth isn't working as expected, but Idk how it looks like. I guess it's somehow related to ProtectedRoute, but this isn't named isAuth. Also, what does useAuthStore do?

I had to just create provider for the store since im using next js , i overlooked this part of the documentation. So it is fully functional now... But thanks :)
